# Gauss divergence Theorem Problem

Tags: analysis, vector-analysis

How do i find the Vectorfield that i need for the Gauss divergence Theorem? I dont know where to start on this one.

The Integral looks like this : $\int_{\partial A}\frac{4x^4+6x^2y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+4y^2+4z^2}}dS^2(x,y,z)$ , where $A=((x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R^3}:x^2+2y^2+2z^2<1)$.

I want to bring it into the form of : $\int_{A}div(F)d\mu$, with a vector field F that im not able to figure out. (I tried finding the divergence of the integrand, but that gives very nasty expressions, so im sure my vector field cant be the integrand.)

I hope someone could at least give me a few hints on where i should start.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint}$: The (not necessarily unit) normal to a surface can be found by taking its gradient

$$F = 0 = x^2 + 2y^2 + 2z^2 - 1 \implies \vec{n} = \nabla (x^2 + 2y^2 + 2z^2-1) = (2x,4y,4z)$$

And the integrand of any vector surface integral is the dot product of a vector field with $\hat{n}$, the *unit* normal of the surface. Can you take it from here?

Comment: So i want to find a F that satisfies $F \cdot \overrightarrow{n}=integrand$ ?

Comment: @bsvgu no, $F\cdot \hat{n}$ there is a very important distinction here

Comment: Ok, ive tried using the unit normal $\hat{n}$ and after some nice cancellation of some factors in the denominator, i got $F=(x^3,\frac{3}{4}x^2y,0)$ as (the?) vector field. If this vector field is correct, i think i will be able to work out the rest on my own, thank you very much !

Comment: The unit normal should be $\frac{\langle x,2y,2z \rangle}{\sqrt{x^2 + 4y^2 + 4z^2}}$. Then you want $F = \langle 4x^3, 3x^2y,0\rangle$.

Comment: Oh right, just take the factor 2 out of the top and get rid of a multiple of 4 in the root.